# modifying Json with Json Slurper in groovy

Tags: java, json, groovy, jsonslurper

I have a scenario where i need to remove one object inside my Json string in groovy. below is the structure of my json. I need to remove "eventLogs" part from my Json.

```
{
  "_id":"123456",
  "type": "prod",
  "metaData" :{...},
  "isUpdated": true,
  "crossId":[...],
  "eventLogs":{...}
}
```

Expected

```
{
  "_id":"123456",
  "type": "prod",
  "metaData" :{...},
  "isUpdated": true,
  "crossId":[...]
}
```

I don't see any remove() function in jsonSlurpur to do this task. please advice.

```
def json = jsonSlurper.parseText(db.get(id).content().toString())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JsonSlurper is a parser of json string to object (map/array) - map in your case.

After parsing you have to modify object and format it back to json string using JsonBuilder (or JsonOutput)

```
def obj = jsonSlurper.parseText(...)
obj.remove('eventLogs')

println new JsonBuilder(obj).toPrettyString()
```

Comment: thanks daggett... did similar thing but forgot to convert it to jsonString. will do that.